# How to use AspNetSqlMembershipProvider for multiple concurrent sessions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm currently implementing a website that require a "customer support" user to Login as the customer itself for support purposes. The problem is that login with the customer user, interrupts the customer support login, so only a single user can be concurrently logged in from a single computer.

I use MVC3 with AspNetSqlMembershipProvider for authorization\authentication purposes.

How can I easly use multiple concurrent logins on a single computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should abstract this at a higher level than the authenticated user.  I suggest that you introduce the concept of a logged in user and a current user.  The session remains with the logged in user, but logged in users with sufficient privileges have the ability to impersonate other users, with that user becoming the current user.  Use the current user to control access to data, drive the UI (with exceptions for what an impersonating user would need to control impersonation), perform transactions, etc.  Store the current user in the session as data, perhaps setting commonly used properties on a base controller in OnActionExecuting as needed.

```
public class AdminController : BaseController
{

    [Authorize( Roles = "ActOnBehalfOfUser" )]
    [AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Get )]
    public ActionResult Impersonate()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize( Roles = "ActOnBehalfOfUser" )]
    [AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Impersonate( string userNameOrID, bool? revoke )
    {
        var currentUser = this.GetCurrentUser();

        if (revoke.HasValue && revoke.Value)
        {
            try
            {
                LogImpersonationEnd( currentUser );
            }
            catch { }
            this.SetEffectiveUser( currentUser );
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( userNameOrID ))
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError( "userNameOrID", "You must supply a username or uid to impersonate." );
                return View();
            }

            var person = this.LookupUser( userNameOrID );
            if (person == null)
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError( "userNameOrID", "No user with the given id was found." );
                return View();
            }

            this.SetEffectiveUser( person );
            try
            {
                using (var dc = new FooDataContext())
                {
                    var impersonation = new Impersonation
                    {
                        EffectiveUser = person.UID,
                        ActualUser = currentUser.UID
                    };
                    dc.InsertOnSubmit( impersonation );
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return View();

    }
}
```

Base Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected bool IsImpersonating
    {
        get
        {
            var effectiveUID = this.Session[EFFECTIVE_USER_KEY] as string;
            var uid = this.Session[USER_KEY] as string;
            return !string.Equals( effectiveUID, uid );
        }
    }

    protected Person GetEffectiveUser()
    {
        return GetUser( this.Session[EFFECTIVE_USER_KEY] as string );
    }

    protected void SetEffectiveUser( Person person )
    {
        this.Session[EFFECTIVE_USER_KEY] = person.UniversityID;
        this.Session[UIPERSON_KEY + person.UniversityID] = person;
    }

    protected Person GetUser( string uid )
    {
        Person person = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( uid ))
        {
            person= GetCachedPerson( uid, p => p.UID == uid );
        }
        return person ?? new AnonymousPerson();
    }



    protected Person LookupUser( string usernameOrUID )
    {
        Person person = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty( usernameOrUID ))
        {
            uiPerson = this.GetCachedPerson( usernameOrUID, p => p.UID== usernameOrUID || p.Username == usernameOrUID );
        }
        return uiPerson;
    }

    private Person GetCachedPerson( string uid, Expression<Func<Person, bool>> selector )
    {
        Person person = this.Session[PERSON_KEY + uid] as Person;
        if (person == null)
        {
            using (var context = new FooDataContext())
            {
                person = context.SingleOrDefault<Person>( selector );
                if (uiPerson != null)
                {
                    this.Session[PERSON_KEY + uid] = person;
                }
            }
        }
        return person;
    }

    protected void LogImpersonationEnd( Person currentUser )
    {
        using (var dc = new FooDataContext())
        {
            var euid = this.GetEffectiveUser().UID;
            var impersonation = dc.Table<Impersonation>()
                                  .Where( i => i.EffectiveUser == euid && i.ActualUser == currentUser.UniversityID && !i.EndTime.HasValue )
                                  .OrderByDescending( i => i.ID )
                                  .FirstOrDefault();

            if (impersonation != null)
            {
                impersonation.EndTime = DateTime.Now;
                dc.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty nifty solution that I'm quite fond of, but I also wonder if isn't it just a workaround for the real solution of writing a new Membership provider, what do you think?

Comment: @EranBetzalel You can still use a membership provider for authentication. In my case it's used with an external authentication source (CAS) to handle single sign-on. This is used to determine who the operational vs. the logged in user is.  It also logs who is impersonating whom for security.  I've left out the bits where the base view model is populated with the operational user (real user is still found on the context).  One advantage of this is that you don't need to share passwords - the support person just has to have the right privilege to become someone else.

Comment: I'll also note that a MembershipProvider doesn't have the right signature to support this.  You'll note that the user object that it returns is the entity model, which in my case is much richer, than an IPrincipal or IIdentity.

Answer (score 1):

Since ASP.NET membership operates using cookies, there isn't a simple programmatic solution that I know of.  However, you could have the support person log in with a different browser (IE and Firefox, for instance).  Or if you had control over the setup of the site, you could provide a different URL for the support person to use: `support.domain.com` versus `www.domain.com` so that the cookie is distinct.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to get the customer support people to log on as the customer in a different browser -e.g. logon as themselves in IE but as the customer in Chrome